# Is it possible to multiply out at least by $s^2$ in this root expression? $\sqrt{(a^2-4d)s^2+(4bd-4ac)s+4c^2}$

Tags: quadratics, radicals

My goal is to pull out all the $s$ from under the square root.

$$\sqrt{(a^2-4d)s^2+(4bd-4ac)s+4c^2}$$

where $a,b,c,d$ are complex numbers and $s$ is a variable.

I tried solving for $s$, but that only gave me $s_1=\frac{2\left(ac+\sqrt{d\left(db^2-2abc+4c^2\right)}-db\right)}{a^2-4d},\:s_2=\frac{2\left(ac-db-\sqrt{d\left(db^2-2abc+4c^2\right)}\right)}{a^2-4d};\quad \:a^2-4d\ne \:0 $

and i realized that i cannot take the squareroot of $(s-s_1)(s-s_2)$ if $s_1$ and $s_2$ are not equal.

**Is it possible to multiply out at least by $s^2$ in this root?**

On the same note is there a general way to check whether a parametric expression has a semi-rational form like:

$$(s\cdot \sqrt{\mathscr{\xi}})$$

?

Where $\xi$ is the irreducible part of the expression(preferably made up of only constants).

Comment: Even if you try to factor just $s$ [let alone $s^2$] out of what's under the radical, it isn't a factor of that quadratic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're asking for some complex $k,l$ such that

$$ks+l=\sqrt{(a^2-4d)s^2+(4bd-4ac)s+4c^2}.$$ Unfortunately, this would make $a,b,c,d$ depend upon $k,l$ and two of their own within the set, or, by excluding $k,l$, have a single dependency. However, we may proceed anyway.

$$k^2s^2+2kls+l^2= (a^2-4d)s^2+4(bd-ac)s+4c^2$$
$$k=\sqrt{a^2-4d}$$ and
$$2\sqrt{a^2-4d}\cdot ls+l^2=4(bd-ac)s+4c^2$$
$$l=\dfrac{2(bd-ac)}{\sqrt{a^2-4d}}$$ leaving the condition
$$(bd-ac)^2c^2=a^2-4d.$$

Comment: That's a smart solution. I didn't think of that!

Comment: @TeresaLisbon A good suggestion. I'll see if I can make it work, but if, in the end, the answer is still as uncomfortably biased as it is, then I would prefer to keep it deleted.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon I hope I have made the adequate adjustments. Please feel free to give me your feedback, thank you.

Comment: @AlexanderConrad Sure. I have upvoted this particular answer of yours as well as the question, I appreciate your recent answers in general, they are to well formed questions and contribute to the quality of the site.